# How to move / copy based on Excel list?

Tags: excel, find, copy, move, id3

I have been given a list of "great music" in Excel format.  Columns include: artist, and song name. I *could* search my personal music, and move / copy to an SD card for listening on the go. But it's a big list.  Is there any way to automate this?

Caveat: several song names may contain spelling errors, and someone seems to have done a mass deletion of the word "The". So "**The Beatles**" are listed as "**Beatles**" and "**I Am The Walrus**" is listed as "**I Am Walrus**".

My web searches have found articles on exporting a file list to Excel, but nothing on using Excel data to find & move / copy. I'm not even sure whether to look in file names for a match, or the **ID3** tag data.

Comment: Davesexcel, I can see how auto-filter lets me search the list provided in Excel. But - how does it search for a corresponding file, in my music collection? And if it finds a match, how does it copy / move the file to a new location?

Comment: I have a You Tube clip on copying files to a different folder. It is not quite what you are asking, but could be a help to you.[Copy Files to a Different Folder](https://youtu.be/vuwi1ZCiS0k)